# PlayOnLinux error in 32bit OpenGL on Ubuntu 16.04. with cuda-8.0

Tags: nvidia, playonlinux, opencl

I am trying to launch PlayOnlinux on 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 with installed cuda-8.0 and binary NVIDIA drives from cuda run file.

I got constant problems with OpenCL libraries.
One that I cannot fix by now is associated with PlayOnLinux. When I launch it, it shows an error:

```
" PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL libraries "
```

If I launch `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so.1` I got the following output:

```
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

To clarify problem:

I have installed `wine:i386` prior playonlinux instalation.
As well, I tried to reinstall the following:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core`

As was mentioned in one of the topics, modifying `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf` could help. The syggestion was to put link to `/usr/lib32` instead of `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/` which I have in my case.

I do not have folder `/usr/lib32` on my system, only `/usr/lib`. Thus, I cannot re-link `libGL.so.1 (libc6)`.

So any suggestions what is missing and how can I link 32bits libs correctly?

P.S. I am interested in keeping cuda-8.0 and binary NVIDIA drivers on my system.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate. In my case, the OpenGL problem is caused by cuda installation. I have installed wine prior playonlinux installation and tried re-install  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386. Still unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Diana have you tried the answer?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yes, I tried different answers from the links above but it did not help. I just reinstalled Ubuntu. It seems that the problem is related to mesa libraries . Actually after installing binary NVIDIA with Cuda it's better not to touch any previously installed mesa libraries as it somehow mess up 32bits libs